# necessary condition for the sum of symmetric matrices to be an orthogonal projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices, projection-matrices

I am trying to prove a version of Cochran's theorem given [here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Esandy/courses/8311/handouts/ch05.pdf). But i am stuck in the following part of the theorem.

**The Problem:-**

Let, $A_1,A_2,A_3,\cdots\cdots, A_m$ be $n \times n$ symmetric matrices, with $rank(A_j)=n_j$ and $A_jA_k=0 ,\forall j\ne k$.

Let $A=\sum A_j$ be an orthogonal projection matrix.

Then, Prove that $A_j$ is an orthogonal projection matrix for all $j$.

**What i have tried:**

$A_i=A_i^T$ is already given and I was able to prove that $\sum A_i = \sum A_i^2$.
I can also prove that the range spaces of the $A_i$'s are disjoint. And this is where I am stuck.
I need to prove that $A_i^2=A_i$. How do i do that?

Comment: What is the title of the book you are working on ?

Comment: the most basic approach: they are real symmetric and commute hence are simultaneously diagonalizable, so consider the implication of $A^2=A$ when each $A_i$ is diagonal but $A_jA_k=0$

Comment: @JeanMarie I am only following the notes that I have linked in the question above. I am not following any book. Also, can somebody tell me why this question was downvoted?

Comment: Upvoted ; there is a handful of people on this site that are harmful by downvoting even when the question is clearly stated and displays work as is the case for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already have most of the answer, and just one more small observation should finalize it for you. First, it is clear that proving the $m=2$ case also proves the general case, so I'll stick to that.

As you already noticed, we are able to prove that $A^2 + B^2 = A+B$. Now, remember that symmetric matrices have a nice property, namely that $\mathbb{R}^n = U \oplus V$, where $U$ and $V$ are the kernel and image of any fixed symmetric matrix $M$. Thus, in particular, we can take $M$ to be $A$ (or $B$). So in our setup, if we can prove that (1) $B^2u = Bu$ for any $u$ in $U$, AND that (2) $B^2v=v$ for any $v$ in $V$, we would be done (of course this also proves that $A^2=A$ because $A$ and $B$ are interchangeable).

(1) Let $u$ be any vector in $U$ (remember that is the kernel of $A$). Since we know that $A^2+B^2=A+B$, we get $$A^2u+B^2u = Au+Bu,$$ and using the fact that $Au=0$ by definition of $u$, we get $$0+B^2u = 0+Bu \implies B^2=B$$ on $U$.

(2) Notice that $BA=0$ is equivalent to saying that the image of $A$ is in the kernel of $B$, or equivalently $B=0$ on $V$. This obviously implies that $B^2=0$ on $V$, and thus $B^2 = B$ on $V$, which completes the proof.

As a summary, we have showed that

(i) $\mathbb{R}^n = U\oplus V$,

(ii) $B^2=B$ on $U$, and

(iiI) $B^2=B$ on $V$.

Hope this was clear, happy to clarify further if need be.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this by manipulating the trace.  The problem statement implies for all $k$ that

$\sum_{j=1}^m A_j^k=A^k = A=\sum_{j=1}^m A_j$
$\implies \sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\big(A_j^k\big)= \text{trace}\big(A\big)= r =\sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\big(A_j\big)$

Now consider arbitrarily large **even power** $k$:
$A_i^k$ has real non-negative eigenvalues (i.e. the square of a real symmetric matrix must be PSD) and observe
$\Big\Vert A_i\Big\Vert_2^k = \Big\Vert A_i^k\Big\Vert_2\leq  \text{trace}\big(A_i^k\big) \leq \sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\big(A_j^k\big)=r$
the boundedness of the operator 2 norm implies all eigenvalue of $A_i$ have modulus $\leq 1$.  Further:

$\sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\big(A_j^4\big) \leq \sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\big(A_j^2\big)$
is met with equality hence each $A_i$ has no eigenvalues of modulus $\in (0,1)$

Thus all eigenvalues of $A_i$ are $\in\big\{-1,0,1\big\}$.  Finally
$\sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\big(A_j\big)\leq \sum_{j=1}^m \text{trace}\big(A_j^2\big)$
and this is met with equality, hence there are no eigenvalues of $-1$.

I.e. each $A_i$ has eigenvalues only $\in \big\{0,1\big\}$ and being real symmetric this means it is an orthogonal projection